# Why does my ASP.NET webpage throw custom 404 error with certain file extensions

Tags: asp.net, http, web, iis

So, I have a folder on my server such like this:

[image]

You can access this resources by the URL:

- Image:

[image]

- Text:

[image]

But the kmz, instead of opening the file (maybe like the text in the xml, I'm not expecting to visualize it) it returns a strange 404:

[image]

Is there any way of allowing all files to be accessed without an error?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, if you wants to access the kmz file in the browser, you will face 404.3 error.

Error details:

```
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.
```

To solve this issue, you should add the MIME map for kmz file.

I suggest you could add below config file into the web.confil, then it will work well.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".kml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".kml" mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml" />
      <remove fileExtension=".kmz" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".kmz" mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kmz" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I can't be as grateful as I would like to. This is just what I needed, thank you very much.